# Java error loginserver

Tags: java

right now i am working on a ban system for a private game of me.
Everything works expect invalid username.
I am getting syntax error on token else.
How i can fix this issue?
I tried to fix this issue by adding else at the bottom but it keeps telling me that i have a syntax error what i need to do to fix this issue? 
I am using the tool eclipse.
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

```
@Override
public void handlePacket(LoginRequestPacket packet, LoginServerHandle handle) {
    handle.getLog().info("Login request received: " + packet);
    Optional<Character> characterOptional = handle.getCharacterByUsername(packet.getUsername());
    Character character = characterOptional.get();


        int ban = character.getBan();
        String ign = character.getIgn();     

        try {
                if (verifyPassword(packet.getPassword(), character.getPasswordHash()) && ban >0) {
                     handle.send(LoginResponsePacket.result(LoginResponsePacket.RESULT_ID_NO_LONGER_IN_USE));
                     handle.getLog().info("Login request " + packet + " response: Banned User.");

                }
                else if (verifyPassword(packet.getPassword(), character.getPasswordHash()) && ign == null) {
                    handle.getLog().info("Login request " + packet + " response: NEW USER!");
                    handle.send(LoginResponsePacket.result(LoginResponsePacket.RESULT_CREATE_CHARACTER));
                    }
                else if (verifyPassword(packet.getPassword(), character.getPasswordHash()))  {   {
                        handle.send(LoginResponsePacket.success(character.getId(), handle.createSession(character), "127.0.0.1"));
                        handle.getLog().info("Successful login: " + packet);
                }

                }

                else { 
            // Incorrect password
            handle.send(LoginResponsePacket.result(LoginResponsePacket.RESULT_INVALID_PW));
            handle.getLog().info("Login request " + packet + " response: Invalid PW");
                }
        }

                 catch (CannotPerformOperationException | InvalidHashException e) {
                    handle.getLog().error("Error performing password validation. Response: Wrong Data.", e);
                    handle.send(LoginResponsePacket.result(LoginResponsePacket.RESULT_WRONG_DATA));
                 }
        else {
            // Invalid username
            handle.getLog().info("Login request " + packet + " response: Invalid ID");
            handle.send(LoginResponsePacket.result(LoginResponsePacket.RESULT_INVALID_ID));
        }
}
 }
```

Comment: yeah i removed it...im a newbie here

Comment: And there is one `}` too much, now there is a `try { } else` which is invalid.

Comment: on which point its to much, i dont see any errors here

Answer (score 1):

Your top level brackets are formed like this

`try` -> `catch` -> `else`

The `else` is not preceeded by an `if`, so the compile fails.

Comment: Yeah, but i want to add the invalid username thing. Everything works expect that.